# Characters in other forms

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

Im pretty sure this has been asked before I just do not know how to phrase it. Mods, maybe we can collapse this questions once a compatible answer has been found?

I have a node.js server and I send a URL to it to read or write JSON data. From the node.js url parser it seems the characters "?" "#" and "&" are reserved while in the JSON.parse/stringify side """ and "'" are reserved as well.

How can I work around this? Its kind of like song data and so these characters can and probably come up in title names.

TIA

Niko

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention something that turned out to be crucial: In the Node side I am using the url and querystring modules which have their own logic manipulating my URL.

Comment: You're going to want to *encode* the URL and *escape* quotes in the JSON to prevent the conflicts.

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent()` but beware as this will not encode single quotes. Another alternative is `escape()`

Comment: I tried the above but in node I am using the url and querystring modules. It seems to take %20 literally and I get %23 instead of an ampersand(for example)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the URL and querystring modules I am using in Node that parse the url according to their own logic I have opted to just treat the query part of my URL as a stringified JSON. I have end-to-end control over the application and so I will just make sure that the URL I send has a stringified JSON as query part of url.